# _TypeError (type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<dynamic>'

Tags: flutter, api, dart

[I am trying to read this API but it is not possible. any ideas?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9CUDc.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S79KJ.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you need to correctly parse the type of the received json-a
see how it's done here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/55292821/8155939